# mpdf unicode output text in white color (not visible)

Tags: php, mpdf

i've converted unicode from mpdf to pdf. But, the unicode color are not visible(white color). Normal texts are black, but only the unicode colors are not visible. Is there any code to change unicode color to black?

```
require_once '../includes/mpdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \mPDF();
$mpdf->SetHeader('|abc|');
$mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
$mpdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = false;
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->debug = true;
$content = strcode2utf($out_data);
$mpdf->SetTextColor(194,8,8);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output('abc.pdf','D');
exit;
```

I'm using mpdf ver 6.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we _UTF-8 All The Way Through_?

Comment: Yes, we are UTF-8. I've used the following for UTF-8:

$content = strcode2utf($out_data);
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
$mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8';

Comment: Provide some examples and show us a minimal example of the code you use.

Comment: Add all question details to your question as an edit, then delete your comments please.

Comment: I've attached my code above. SetTextColor(); worked for non-unicode texts, but the unicodes are still invisible(white).

Comment: Show your actual HTML/CSS code (as small example as possible).

Comment: And please remove the duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51697196/mpdf-ive-generated-unicode-output-but-the-characters-are-set-as-colortranspar